# Выбор значения либо из текстового поля, либо из списка

Tags: html, php

Как такое реализовать?

Всем привет, у меня есть это :

```
<select name="client_city1" id = "client[1]" onChange = "change()">
    <option value="Москва" selected="selected">Москва</option>
    <option value="Петербург">Петербург</option>
    <option value="Киев">Киев</option>
    <option value="Калининград">Калининград</option>
    <option value="Белгород">Белгород</option>
    <option value="Харьков">Харьков</option>
    <option value="0">Другой город</option>
</select>
    <div id = "other_1">
    Другой: <input type="text" name="client_city1">
    <script language="javascript">
    </script>
    </div>
```

Так вот мне нужно сделать так в php коде, чтобы если в

```
<select> выбрано <option value="0">Другой город</option>
```

То значение выбралось из текстового поля, а если что-то другое, то уже из списка, у меня почему-то получается, только либо с текстового поля, либо со списка, а как это соединить вместе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод передачи форм какой? 
**Решение:**
 1. Поменяйте в select'e `name="client_city1"` на `name="client_city"`;
 2. Определите метод передачи формы и выберите нужный фрагмент кода;

Для МЕТОДА  **POST**:

```
 IF($_POST['client_city'] == "0")
   $client_city = $_POST['client_city1'];
 else 
  $client_city = $_POST['client_city'];
```

Для МЕТОДА  **GET**:

```
 IF($_GET['client_city'] == 0)
   $client_city = $_GET['client_city1'];
 else 
  $client_city = $_GET['client_city'];
```

3.Сохраните и пользуйтесь.

Comment: Вы поменяли название select'a?

Comment: Не работает, когда я выбираю из списка, то ничего не выводит после отправки формы, а если ввожу в поле, то всё нормально.

Да, поменял название.

Comment: все должно работать

Comment: Проблему решил взяв 0 в двойные кавычки, кому интересно вот рабочий код:

    IF($_POST['client_city'] == "0")
      $client_city = $_POST['client_city1'];
    else 
      $client_city = $_POST['client_city'];

Спасибо **Node_pro**

Comment: сглупил, исправил =)